# Does the $\forall$-theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot,0,1)$ have a finite or at worst recursive axiomatization?

Tags: model-theory

By Godel's incompleteness theorem, the theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot,0,1)$ does not have a recursive axiomatization. However, what about the $\forall$-theory of that same structure? Does it have a finite or at worst recursive axiomatization? And if so, can someone exhibit a set of axioms for the $\forall$-theory of that structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: by the MRDP theorem, the $\forall$-theory of $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot,0,1)$ is co-r.e.-complete. (Note that it is clearly co-r.e. in the first place, since a counterexample to a $\forall$-sentence can be verified.)

For what it's worth, Godel's theorem actually comes very close to proving that already. Specifically, the proof can be unwound to show that the $\Pi^0_1$ fragment of the theory is not recursively axiomatizable. However, $\Pi^0_1$ is a bit broader than $\forall$ since it allows **bounded quantifiers**, and to bring things down to the level of $\forall$-sentences as such we need to do a surprising amount of work.